# How to pass CommandName of LinkButton in GridView to OnClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to pass the CommandName on my LinkButton to the OnClick event within my GridView in Asp.net Webforms (C#)?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadFile" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="OpenModal" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Customer_ID") %>' CommandName="PassThisName"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I know it's possible in the RowCommand of the GridView like this:

```
if (e.CommandName == "PassThisName")
{
}
```

But I need to get this value in the OnClick event.

Comment: Yes its possible please take a look [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Any specific reason that you want onclick eventhandler for a link button which is inside a GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, you can do it like this:

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdCustomer">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadFile" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Customer_ID") %>' CommandName="PassThisName"></asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void DownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkDownloadFile = (LinkButton)sender;
    string commandName = lnkDownloadFile.CommandName;
}
```